# Deleting deployment leaves trailing replicasets and pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running Kubernetes in GCP and since updating few months ago (now I am running `1.17.13-gke.2600`) I am observing trailing replicasets and pods after deployment deletion. Consider state before deletion:

```
$ k get deployment | grep parser
parser-devel                              1/1     1       1        38d
$ k get replicaset | grep parser
parser-devel-66bfc86ddb                   0       0       0        27m
parser-devel-77898d9b9d                   1       1       1      5m49s
$ k get pod | grep parser
parser-devel-77898d9b9d-4w48w             1/1     Running 0       6m2s
```

Then I delete the deployment:

```
$ k delete deployment parser-devel
deployment.apps "parser-devel" deleted
$ k get replicaset | grep parser
parser-devel-66bfc86ddb                   0       0       0        28m
parser-devel-77898d9b9d                   1       1       1       7m1s
$ k get pod | grep parser
parser-devel-77898d9b9d-4w48w             1/1     Running 0       7m6s
```

Then I try to delete the replicasets:

```
$ k delete replicaset parser-devel-66bfc86ddb parser-devel-77898d9b9d
replicaset.apps "parser-devel-66bfc86ddb" deleted
replicaset.apps "parser-devel-77898d9b9d" deleted
$ k get pod | grep parser
parser-devel-77898d9b9d-4w48w             1/1     Running 0      8m14s
```

As far as I understand Kubernetes, this is not a correct behaviour, so why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

How about check ownerReference of the ReplicaSet created by you Deployment ? Refer [Owners and dependents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#owners-and-dependents) for more details. For example, for removing dependencies of the Deployment, the Deployment name and uid should be matched exactly in the ownerReference ones. Or I have experience that similar issue happened, if Kuerbetenes API was somthing wrong. So API service restart may help to resovle it.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  ...
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    controller: true
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    kind: Deployment
    name: your-deployment
    uid: xxx
```

Comment: The ownerReferences correctly exists, but unfortunately seem to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The  trailing ReplicaSets that you can see after deployment deletion depends of the [Revision History Limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#revision-history-limit) that you have in your Deployment.

`.spec.revisionHistoryLimit` is an optional field that specifies the number of old ReplicaSets to retain to allow rollback.
By default, 10 old ReplicaSets will be kept.

You could see the number of ReplicaSets with the following command:

```
kubectl get  deployment DEPLOYMENT -o yaml | grep revisionHistoryLimit
```

But you can modify this value with:

```
kubectl edit deployment DEPLOYMENT
```

#### Edit 1

I created a GKE cluster on the same version (1.17.13-gke.2600) in order to know if it is deleting trailing resources when I delete the parent object (Deployment).

With  testing purposes, I created an [nginx Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) and then deleted it with `kubectl delete Deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME`, Deployment and all its dependents (Pods created and Replicasets) were deleted.

Then I tested it again, but this time by adding kubectl flag `--cascade=false` like `kubectl delete Deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME --cascade=false` and all the dependent resources remained but the Deployment. With this situation (leaving orphaned resources) kube-controller manager (Specifically garbage collector) should delete these resources soon or later.

With the tests I made, seems that GKE version is OK as I was able to delete the trailed resources made by the Deployment object I created since my first test.

Cascade option is set by default as `true` with different and several command verbs like [`delete`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#delete), you also could check this other [documentation](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_delete/). Even so, I would like to know if you can create a Deployment, and then try to delete it with command `kubectl delete Deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME --cascade=true` in order to know if by trying to force cascade deletion helps on this case.

Comment: Did you read my issue? You seem to answer something completely else.

Comment: @Vojtěch, Sorry about the confusion with my original post I edited it, I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I tried `kubectl delete Deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME --cascade=true` but no effect - only deployment is deleted. I think it might be something with @Daein's answer as the ownerReferences are completely missing.